# Why does Olde English 800 taste so bad?

Tags: recipe

I think most people will agree that the 8-ball tastes like no other beer. Any conjectures on how exactly it is prepared to make it taste that bad? I am actually really curious on what the ingredient make up is.

It's not just malt liquor, OE really is in a class of its own.

I've found a recipe [here](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f13/want-make-olde-english-800-clone-52663/) but there is no way that its going to come out like OE.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an opinion about a commercial beer.  It has nothing to do with homebrewing.

Comment: I don't think that its off topic. It sounds as if fthinker is wanting to clone this commercial beer, and needs to understand why the commercial beer is flavored a certain way.

Comment: I was about to close this as "opinion-based", myself.  I don't think this is a particularly valuable contribution to the SE.

Comment: Graham speaks what I was thinking. However, I do understand where Denny Conn is coming from and realize now that this is really a question about a commercial beer. Just to clarify, I wanted to know what kind of processing was going into OE and how this differs from standard beer production. This is basically a commercial beer question and not one about home brewing in the end.

Comment: Given your last comment, I think you should consider re-posting this on [beer.se], @fthinker. That said, you may wish to alter the tone a bit if you're interested in the ingredients / brewing process rather than just inviting opinionated rants about OE. PS: if you do re-post, delete this question.